# jQuery hover animation won't work after fadeOut

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am modifying the [Adipoli](http://cube3x.com/adipoli-jquery-image-hover-plugin/) jQuery plugin to create an image transition on hover. It is set to make the image grayscale, then on mouseenter it does an animation into the original image, then on mouseleave it goes back to grayscale. I've made it so it fades out slowly into grayscale on mouseleave, but afterwards it won't do the mouseenter animation anymore. The mouseenter animation will only fire once. 
How can I get it to continue firing?

The line was originally: `$(this).children('.adipoli-after').html('').hide();`

Changed to: `$(this).children('.adipoli-after').fadeOut();`.

([Full jquery plugin code here.](http://pastebin.com/3yMceibs))

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to use a function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#nameOfId").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).fadeOut();
});
});
```

Comment: Are you saying to use that in addition to what I stated above, or instead of? And where should this be placed?

Comment: I don't know exactly how you want the animation and what not but go here http://jqueryui.com/animate/ and download the plug in and read that.. that is all the tool that you will need and instructions.. To sum it up you would need the help of not just Jquery but Jquery UI (User Interface).. Jquery does not support the animation() of colors so you need the help of Jquery UI and after downloading it just link it to you HTML along with your .js file with your actual Jquery code for the animation. and you should be good to go from there. Sounds like a lot but its pretty simple just read JqueryUI.

Comment: To clarify: I have successfully gotten the color animation to work correctly, both on mouseenter and mouseleave – The issue is that it will only happen once.